# WPF XAML can not see checkboxes in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm working on a small WPF project,

for now it contains one window which should display as much checkboxes are many values in lists are.

For testing purposes, before I get values from database I tried something like this:

```
public class StatusOption
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public void GetSerialNumbers()
{
   List<StatusOption> serialNumbers = new List<StatusOption>();

   for(int i = 0; i<10;i++)
   {
       StatusOption x = new StatusOption();
       x.name = "Random name" + i;
       x.IsSelected = false;
       serialNumbers.Add(x);
    }

}
```

And my xaml looks like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="SerialNumbersListBox"
         AllowDrop="True"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                 Grid.Row="2"
         ItemsSource="{Binding GetSerialNumbers}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding serialNumbers}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

But unfortunatelly nothing is displayed below textbox...

But for now everything is empty, and I can not find out why..

Thanks guys
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not bind a method. Please use property instead.

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="171" Margin="334,96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="248" AllowDrop="True"  x:Name="SerialNumbersListBox"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding SerialNumbers}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding name}"
                              IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>


public class SerialNumbersListBoxViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public class StatusOption
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<StatusOption> _SerialNumbers;
    public ObservableCollection<StatusOption> SerialNumbers
    {
        get
        {
            return _SerialNumbers;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _SerialNumbers)
            {
                _SerialNumbers = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SerialNumbers));
            }

        }

    }

    public void GetSerialNumbers()
    {
        if (_SerialNumbers == null)
            _SerialNumbers = new ObservableCollection<StatusOption>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            StatusOption x = new StatusOption();
            x.name = "Random name" + i;
            x.IsSelected = false;
            _SerialNumbers.Add(x);
        }

    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public SerialNumbersListBoxViewModel()
    {
        GetSerialNumbers();

        }
}
```

You can refer this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/806587/basic-mvvm-listbox-binding-in-wpf) for more details

Regard!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind to methods, you can only bind to Properties or DependencyProperties.

So you need to create a Property for your `serialNumbers`. You should also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so that the `ListBox` can know when your property changed.

```
public List<object> SerialNumbers
{
    get => this._serialNumbersProperty;
    set
    {
        if (!List<object>.Equals(value, this._serialNumbersProperty))
        {
            this._serialNumbersProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.SerialNumbers));
        }
    }
}

<ListBox x:Name="SerialNumbersListBox"
     AllowDrop="True"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
             Grid.Row="2"
     ItemsSource="{Binding SerialNumbers}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding name}"
                  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```